# SharePoint: Search folders by name that are subfolders of a document library

Tags: c#, sharepoint, service

I want to search all subfolders of a document library in SharePoint that have a certain title. I am using the service.asmx web service.

Somehow It does not work. I get no results and do not know how to fix the problem.

My Code looks like this:

```
 var service = new SharePointSearchService1.QueryService();
 service.PreAuthenticate = true;

 service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

 var queryXml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>";
 queryXml += "<QueryPacket xmlns=\"urn:Microsoft.Search.Query\">";
 queryXml +=     "<Query>";
 queryXml +=         "<SupportedFormats>";
 queryXml +=             "<Format>urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Folder:Folder</Format>";
 queryXml +=         "</SupportedFormats>";
 queryXml +=         "<Context>";
 queryXml +=              "<QueryText language=\"de-DE\" type=\"MSSQLFT\">SELECT Size, Rank, Path, Title, Description, Write FROM scope() WHERE  CONTAINS(Path, '\"http://sharepoint/area/test/Test Projects/*\"') </QueryText>";
 queryXml +=         "</Context>";
 queryXml +=         "<Range>";
 queryXml +=             "<StartAt>1</StartAt>";
 queryXml +=             "<Count>5000</Count>";
 queryXml +=         "</Range>";
 queryXml +=     "</Query>";
 queryXml += "</QueryPacket>";

 var result = service.Query(queryXml);
```

The above code does not work. What I expect is to get all items (like folder) that are located inside the document library (Test Projects).

I can search items with the following query:

```
queryXml += "<QueryText language=\"de-DE\" type=\"MSSQLFT\">SELECT Size, Rank, Path, Title, Description, Write FROM scope() WHERE  CONTAINS(Title, '\"AA*\"') </QueryText>";
```

But this returns results from the whole site. I only want to have items that are in the document library and in subfolders of this library.

I also tryed using the "like" predicate but that did not return anything, too.

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?